# Rails read base64 string from uploaded file without saving the file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, encoding, file-io, request, base64

For my Ruby on Rails project I have a form that lets user upload a file (say, a jpg file for an image). I do not want to save that image as a file anywhere in my app. I want to extract the base64 string of the image uploaded, however.

So for the form I have (I'm using Slim)

```
 = form_tag somepath, method: :post, remote: true do
   .form-group
        = label_tag :file
        = file_field_tag :file
```

Then in controller I have

```
def allowed_params
  params.permit([:file])
end
```

However, when doing `File.open(allowed_params[:file], 'rb'){|f| f.read}` after uploading a file `photo.jpg` using the UI, I got error `Errno::ENOENT Exception: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - C:\fakepath\photo.jpg`

I tried `Base64.encode64(File.open('someotherfile.jpg').read)` where `someotherfile.jpg` is a file which I know where it is and valid and it worked out well.

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you make sure you're using a multipart form? You can do this by setting `multipart: true` in your `form_tag` helper (e.g. `form_tag somepath, method: :post, remote: true, multipart: true`). Then you *should* be able to access the contents in the controller via `allowed_params[:file].read`.